# How can I achieve multidatatrigger, multitrigger and multivalue converter functionality

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am just playing around with uwp, and I found it very limiting comparing to wpf.
Let’s say I want to do something when a mouse is over and a property that my control is bound too is false, then do something. Here is an example

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
     <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListboxItem},
      Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true" />
     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsRequired}" Value="false" />
  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#383838" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Any ideas? The above is so useful and so flexible. Not to mention multidatatrigger which could achieve even more.

Kind Regards

Comment: Would a composite state trigger help you in any way? Check out this example: https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers/blob/master/src/TestApp/Samples/CompositeSample.xaml

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll have a look at it tonight, and see what I can do with it.

Answer (score -1):

Try playing around with [{x:Bind}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx) instead of {Binding}.

You may need to rework quite a bit, but if you look at the referenced page you can see the differences (from Silverlight, RT/8)

```
<object property="{x:Bind}" .../>
```

-or-

```
<object property="{x:Bind propertyPath}" .../>
```

-or-

```
<object property="{x:Bind bindingProperties}" .../>
```

-or-

```
<object property="{x:Bind propertyPath, bindingProperties}" .../>
```